# What's happening to my tulips?

Tags: watering, tulips

I recently transplanted some tulips bought at wilko, in a mixture of irish moss peat, compost and a little vermiculite. The last week has been unexpectedly hot, but I tried to water them regularly and noticed a very fast drainage, actually. This is their condition now. Is this due to their exposition in the full hot sun? Or to lack of water? Or the mix I used? Thanks!

[image]
[image][image]

Comment: Which variety of tulip is it supposed to be? And how deep are the pots you planted them in? At what stage was their growth when you moved them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tulips are ideally transplanted during their dormant period (before they flower), which is in the autumn if you live in the northern hemisphere, or during the spring if you live in the southern hemisphere. Planting bulbs in the autumn enables a strong root system to form, which supports the plant during its flowering stage. Transplanting plants while its already flowering (when it uses a lot of resources) risks damaging the roots and the direct sun exposure further stresses the plant.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it's probably a combination of being transplanted and then being subjected to sun and heat. When transplanting in the spring and summer while the plants need to hold on to as much water as they can (I don't mean watering a lot, I mean holding on to what they already have), you want to keep them cool and shaded so they aren't respiring so much.